# Jquery keyup only working in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a basic cost calculator that I want to automatically add values as numbers are entered into the text fields. This works perfect in Chrome, but for some reason only in chrome. My goal is to have the new math results show up after the dollar sign whenever a number is entered into the text field. I am getting no console errors and JS Hint/Lint both look good.

Any ideas why this is working in chrome, but no where else?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Egreg87/j7r4zte8/4/

```
window.onload = function() {


$('input').keyup(function(){ // run anytime the value changes

    var duration =  parseFloat($('#duration').val()) || 0; // get value of field
    var timeHr =  parseFloat($('#timeHr').val()) || 0; // get value of field
    var distance = parseFloat($('#distance').val()) || 0; // get value of field
    var flight = parseFloat($('#flight').val()) || 0; // convert it to a float
    var parkDays = parseFloat($('#parkDays').val()) || 0;
    var parking = '12.00';
    var fuelCost= '3.50';

    $('#added').html(flight + parkDays * parking + distance * (2) / (20) * fuelCost + timeHr); // add them and output it

    });

$('input').keyup(function(){ // run anytime the value changes

    var distance1 = parseFloat($('#distance1').val()) || 0; // get value of field
    var flight1 = parseFloat($('#flight1').val()) || 0; // convert it to a float
    var parkDays = parseFloat($('#parkDays').val()) || 0;
    var parking1 = '12.00';
    var fuelCost1= '3.50';

    $('#added1').html(flight1 + parkDays * parking1 + distance1 * (2) / (20) * fuelCost1); // add them and output it

    });

$('input').keyup(function(){ // run anytime the value changes

    var duration2 =  parseFloat($('#duration2').val()) || 0; // get value of field
    var timeHr =  parseFloat($('#timeHr').val()) || 0; // get value of field
    var distance2 = parseFloat($('#distance2').val()) || 0; // get value of field
    var flight2 = parseFloat($('#flight2').val()) || 0; // convert it to a float
    var parkDays = parseFloat($('#parkDays').val()) || 0;
    var parking2 = '12.00';
    var fuelCost2= '3.50';

    $('#added2').html(flight2 + parkDays * parking2 + distance2 * (2) / (20) * fuelCost2); // add them and output it

});




<!--Caclulator fields-->

<div id="calc-fields">  
<div>
<label class="main3">MGM</label><br>
<label>Total Cost of Your Flight(s) from MGM $:</label>
<input name="numeric" class="allownumericwithdecimal" id="flight"></input><br />

<label for="distance">Distance (miles): </label>
<input type="text" class="number" name="distance" id="distance"></input>
<label for="duration">Drive Time (minutes): </label>
<input type="text" name="duration" id="duration"  class="drive-time"></input>


<label class="main">Total Cost from MGM: <br>$</label>
<span id="added" class="main2"></span><br />



</div>

<div>
<label class="main3">ATL</label><br>
<label>Total Cost of Your Flight(s) from ATL $:</label>
<input name="numeric" class="allownumericwithdecimal" id="flight1"></input><br />
<label for="distance1">Distance (miles): </label>
<input type="text" name="distance1" id="distance1"></input>
<label  for="duration1">Drive Time (minutes): </label>
<input type="text" name="duration1" id="duration1"  class="drive-time"></input>




<label class="main">Total Cost from ATL:<br> $</label>
<span id="added1" class="main2"></span><br />

</div>

<div>
<label class="main3">BHM</label><br>
<label>Total Cost of Your Flight(s) from BHM $:</label>
<input name="numeric" class="allownumericwithdecimal" id="flight2"></input><br />
<label for="distance2">Distance (miles): </label>
<input type="text" name="distance2" id="distance2"></input>
<label for="duration">Drive Time (minutes):</label>
<input type="text" name="duration2" id="duration2"  class="drive-time"></input>


<label class="main">Total Cost from BHM: <br>$</label>
<span id="added2" class="main2"></span><br />


</div>

<br>
<hr></hr>



        <!--End calc fields-->
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me in Chrome. The code in your fiddle isn't the same as the question, it uses `$('input').bind('propertychange input paste', ...)`, not `$('input').keyup(...)`.

Comment: Your fiddle will also not work in Chrome as you have `window.onload = ... ` there and the `onLoad` option on the left. If you correct this it also seems to work with FF.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work in Chrome, nor Firefox - if I change your fiddle - to "no wrap" - in <body> it works: http://jsfiddle.net/j7r4zte8/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things- changed to document ready. You were defining a function calc1 as you were passing it as a call back, changed to anonymous function. In stead on .keyup changed to on('keyup')
If you take the time to look at console errors, things like this will never be an issue for you..
Below is fixed jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/j7r4zte8/7/

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(){ //vs  $('input').keyup(function calc1()
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved my weekend. I apologize I had the wrong version of the fiddle listed in the post, it was one I was playing around with. That's why there was some oddities in there.

Ultimately what ended up being the solution was that I needed to change my Jquery loader to $(function() {} instead of window.onload = function() {}

After I changed that it worked in IE. I am going to try to research why that is.